# Statements equivalent to the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

I was wondering if there are any statements that could help forming an opinion on whether the CH is "true" or not.

I am thus looking for all statements, preferably of this character or simple ones, which are equivalent to the CH.

Comment: The title might be a bit misleading, but it's essentially a question about statements [more or less] equivalent to CH.

Comment: Sierpinski wrote a 192 page book in 1934, [**Hypothèse du Continu**](https://eudml.org/doc/219323), that is entirely devoted to this issue. The book is freely available on the internet, but it's written in French and as far as I know it has not been translated to English.